# Problema idioma recaptcha google

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Tengo un problema con el recaptcha de Google en un formulario, ya que le tenemos puesto que se cargue en un idioma en concreto pero a veces carga en español y otras en el idioma que le tenemos forzado.

Lo tenemos puesto así cuando carga el formulario para que el recaptcha sea en portugues

```
jQuery.getScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt', function(){
});
```

Pues en ocasiones el texto que sale es "Nao sou un robo" y otras pone "No soy un robot".

En principio con el hl deberia forzar el idioma, pero parece que no es así.

¿Sabéis porque puede pasar?

Gracias!

Comment: Sin tener más datos es difícil saberlo a ciencia cierta, pero a priori diría que se trata de un tema de asincronía. La función `getScript()` lanza una llamada asíncrona (eso significa que no espera el resultado de la llamada, por lo que el código puede seguir ejecutándose) y dependiendo de lo que tarde esta a veces podría ejecutarse el cambio a portugués después de que el captcha se muestre, quedando este en español, que seguramente sea el que tenéis puesto por defecto.

Comment: Hola phpMyGuel.

me podria cuadrar lo que dices, ya que he leido que por defecto el recaptcha se pone en el idioma del usuario, y el parametro hl fuerza el idioma, pero si es una función asincrona, quizás en algunos momentos carga el formulario antes de la respuesta del recaptcha... y por eso en ocasiones se ve en español y otras en portugues.